# How to fetch length of paragraph at xml using lua script

Tags: sql, xml, string, lua, postgresql-9.5

How to fetch count of XML Text paragraph using lua script.

```
boxno = string.len(xml, 'parstyle="Text"')
myvar.message = tostring(boxno)
```

Comment: Why are you passing 2 values to `string.len`? what do you expect `string.len` to do with both of those values?

Comment: I need length of particular XML tag(eg:<text>.....</text>)